# Where to find Plantin font?

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for a font package that supports Plantin. Do you have any suggestions? I can't find it in the LaTeX font catalogue.

Comment: It’s a commercial font; you need to buy a license and then use `fontspec`.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use the font in a LaTeX-specific format? Usually that is only necessary if you're stuck with the old compiler PDFLaTeX. If you used the more modern LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you are free to use any font in a more common format that can be installed in your operating system.

Comment: https://catalog.monotype.com/family/monotype/plantin